# In France , what language is the Cisco IOS for routers and switches?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios

If I accept a Network Engineer job in France, what language will the Cisco , Juniper, etc, IOS communicate in?

If it is in French, is there an acceptable workaround that I can install in routers that will allow me to interact in English?

Thank you.

Matt.

Comment: IOS isn't ever localized.

Comment: The CLI is always "english". Other various UI's may have localization. (eg. ASDM, SSLVPN client, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco IOS commands are only in English.  You can get manuals and datasheets in other languages.